# Assign list of objects to multiple variables

Tags: python, polygon, sympy

I have list like this my_list = [(1,2),(5,3),(3,6),(9,7)], I want output like this a = (1,2), b=(5,3),c=(3,6),d=(9,7). Based on list size variables may increases Or decreases

Comment: "Based on list size variables may increases Or decreases" - no! Keep the list. Don't try to use dynamically named variables here. Even where they're supported (mostly just global scopes), dynamic variables are way more awkward all around than just working with the list directly.

Comment: `my_list = [chr(y)+'={}'.format(x) for x, y in zip(my_list, range(97, 123))]` gives you a list which then you can iterate using a loop

Comment: or you can do this: `for x, y in zip(my_list, range(97,123)):
    print('{} = {}'.format(chr(y), x))`

Comment: `a,b,c,d=[(1,2),...]` is easy, but not suitable for an unknown number. Generally we don't recommend open ended assignments. It is rarely necessary.

Comment: Basically, My intention is to find the centroid of the N-Polygon using sympy module. so I have a list with all Points. Here sympy official doc: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/polygons.html (we can see centroid)

Comment: @RamaKrishna: This kind of sounds like you don't know about function argument unpacking. You can call a function like `f(*some_list)` to pass the elements of a list as separate arguments. You don't need to assign the elements to separate variables first.

Comment: Thanks .Really I don't know about function argument unpacking. Thanks lot